# HTML 5 and its learning resources

Tags: html

as new to HTML 5 and willing to learn it core and form start. Can you all please share your best sites that you followed.

Love to have tutorials sites from where i can learn, and Showcases so that i get inspiration.

thanks for writing in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [**Dive Into HTML5** by Mark Pilgrim](http://diveintohtml5.info/)

is a well-written, humorous and very understandable online book that covers *everything* you need to know to get started with HTML5.

It also comes with lovely illustrations!

> **Table of contents:**
>
> 1. [Introduction: Five Things You Should Know About HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/introduction.html)
> 2. [A Quite Biased History of HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/past.html)
> 3. [Detecting HTML5 Features: It’s Elementary, My Dear Watson](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html)
> 4. [What Does It All Mean?](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html)
> 5. [Let’s Call It a Draw(ing Surface)](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)
> 6. [Video in a Flash (Without That Other Thing)](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html)
> 7. [You Are Here (And So Is Everybody Else)](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)
> 8. [A Place To Put Your Stuff](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)
> 9. [Let’s Take This Offline](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html)
> 10. [A Form of Madness](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html)
> 11. [“Distributed,” “Extensibility,” And Other Fancy Words](http://diveintohtml5.info/extensibility.html)
> 12. [The All-In-One Almost-Alphabetical No-Bullshit Guide to Detecting Everything](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html)
> 13. [HTML5 Peeks, Pokes and Pointers](http://diveintohtml5.info/peeks-pokes-and-pointers.html)

Answer (score 2):

I really like [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/)
I guess you can learn a lot by looking into the well-organized archives.